# Reading XML file to Temp-table in Progress-4gl

Tags: xml, progress-4gl

I'm using **OpenEdge 10.2A**.

My XML file has only one **TABLE_NAME** record and it has many fields but a simplified version is:

```
<Table_Name>
    <Field_Name_1>Value_1</Field_Name_1>
    <Field_Name_2>Value_2</Field_Name_2>
</Table_Name>
```

In order to read it, I use the code:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE Table_Name NO-UNDO
    FIELD Field_Name_1 AS CHAR
    FIELD Field_Name_2 AS CHAR
.

TEMP-TABLE Table_Name:READ-XML("File","C:\myFile.xml","empty",?,?,?,?).

DEF VAR i AS INT NO-UNDO.
FOR EACH Table_Name: 
    i=i + 1.
END.
DISP i.
```

It displays **0** (zero) as the result, meaning it does not read the XML records in the file.

If I change my XML file as follows:

```
<My_XML_Records>
      <Table_Name>
          <Field_Name_1>Value_1</Field_Name_1>
          <Field_Name_2>Value_2</Field_Name_2>
      </Table_Name>
</My_XML_Records>
```

the same code displays **1** (one)

Since XML files are produced by other programs and the format is fixed, is there a way to make the code to read the XML files properly?

Comment: What version are you on? The code where you get 0 records work for me. Pehaps there's something else that's wrong?

Comment: Very strange, our version is OpenEdge 10.2A build 1185. I have run the procedure using procedure editor and without changing the code, adding My_XML_Records tag gives the desired output. Which version do you use?

Comment: 11.7 so a lot newer... Might be its fixed

Comment: yes a lot newer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known bug, I found a Knowledge Base entry for it:
https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/How-to-read-an-XML-in-a-temp-table-using-READ-XML

The workaround: In your XML, you're going to need an outer node with the dataset name. Like this:

```
<dataset_name>
    <Table_Name>
        <Field_Name_1>Value_1</Field_Name_1>
        <Field_Name_2>Value_2</Field_Name_2>
    </Table_Name>
</dataset_name>
```

And then define a dataset for your temp-table. So here's the code:

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE Table_Name 
    FIELD Field_Name_1 AS CHAR
    FIELD Field_Name_2 AS CHAR
.

define dataset dataset_name for table_name.

dataset dataset_name:read-xml("File","C:\myFile.xml","empty",?,?,?).
DEF VAR i AS INT NO-UNDO.
FOR EACH Table_Name: 
    i=i + 1.
    DISP Field_Name_1 format "x(20)" 
         Field_Name_2 format "x(20)".
END.
DISP i.
```

I got the dataset loaded with that.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, since it is a known bug, I have to read the xml file and change its structure save it and reload it. Your help is appriciated. Thanks again.